# Bootstrap HTML carriage return

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After one hour for isolating the problem, I can post this :)

I've a problem with local file but not in production. THe only difference is that on production, html files are inlined.

I'm using default bootstrap 3.3.5 and this css class :

```
<style>
    .v-center {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
</style>
```

My problem is that I don't have the same result with both code :

Code 1 :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 v-center">
        col-md-4
    </div><div class="col-md-8 v-center">
        col-md-8
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: TEST]
Code 2 :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 v-center">
        col-md-4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 v-center">
        col-md-8
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: TEST2]

You can found here two examples :

http://relationeo.com/test.html

http://relationeo.com/test2.html

The bug is happening when window with is > 990px.

Why the carriage return breaks the col ?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your CSS class "v-center". It sets the display to `inline-block`. With `inline-block` white space comes into play (at least the first character of white space, anyways). Just as you would expect:

```
Just
Testing
```

To be rendered as `Just Testing` rather than `JustTesting`, the same applies to inline or inline-block elements.

Long and short, don't mess with the Bootstrap grid if you expect to have consistent results. If you need to apply other classes, do so *within* the grid div, not on the same div. For example:

```
<div class="col-md-8"> <!-- this is grid div, so no other classes here -->
    <div class="v-center">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```